# Can I add a triple crank to my old signet centurion road bike?

Tags: crankset

I have an old signet centurion 12 speed road bike. The bike is in very good shape.  I'm older now and want to start riding again without buying a new bike.   I would like to add lower gears to deal with the hills around me.  It current has a 170mm 52/42 custom (brand name) crankset.  Can I easily add a triple crankset to this bike to get the gearing I want?  Does the front derailleur also need to be changed?

Comment: What kind of gearing in the rear do you have? A six speed freewheel? What derailleur? What kind of shifters? You might achieve good gearing by other means.

Comment: The rear is a 6 speed cassette.  The shifters are friction type. The derailleurs are Shimano.  The only Id I could find was the name "Skylark"  on the derailleur.

Comment: Really cassette and not freewheel?

Comment: Nope, my bad, freewheel.

Answer (score 3):

You probably could, but it is not clear if you should. You could get some compact (50-34) or even subcompact (e.g. 46-30) double crankset. That looks like a better option to me. A different front derailleur might but does not have to be necessary depending on what you can put up with. Witj a triple you almost certainly need a new front derailleur (although again not completely strictly) and most likely the shifter although a friction shifter could stay.

With a six speed freewheel you do not have that much choicein the back. You can try to get some Megarange freewheel 14-34 or similar. It has the biggest sprocket (granny gear (much larger than the other ones).

Modern cassettes with large ranges would require much bigger changes including a new wheel (just changing the hub is unlikely to be worth it) and widening the rear frame spacing (there is some leeway with steel).

Comment: The compact 50-34 seems to be the better idea.

Comment: @C.J. Better than what? Than a triple? I tend to agree. But it is still better to pair it with a larger sprocket in the back. I certainly do find good use for a 32T sprocket in the rear. I do not agree that anything over 24 is like walking. It depends on your cadence.

Answer (score 2):

### Possibly, but there's not enough information to say for sure

If were able to add a 3X crankset, then you would absolutely need a new derailleur and probably a new shifter. The best thing for you to do if to take this to your bike shop and have them look at it. They'll be able to tell you if you can get a 3X crank with the bottom bracket you have. If you can't get a 3X, ask them about getting new chainring (maybe like a 39/50) or a new cassette.

Comment: The shifter might be a friction one and could stay.

Comment: @VladimirF Edited, thanks

Comment: The rear is a 6 speed freewheel. The shifters are friction type. The derailleurs are Shimano. The only Id I could find was the name "Skylark" on the derailleur.

Answer (score 1):

I really appreciate all the feedback.  Thank You all.

The keyword in the original post was "easily"  As in just a quick swap of the crank set possibly. I'm not opposed to trying any of the approaches given. My fear is if I start to change out anything it will not get finished and no riding will take place.

So....I'm going to go with "if it aint broke dont fix it" approach.  :-)

Again, thank you for the feedback it was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

What a coincidence, I had a similar issue with a Centurion road bike with 6x2 transmission.

I think the freewheel was 14-26, but the largest sprocket was too worn to engage the chain, so it was useless, rendering the bike a 5x2.

At the time I began using this bike, I had been riding MTB with 11-34 cassette and a 22-32-42 Triple crankset for quite a long time (I was used to spin up on hills, rather than grind). I also live in a very hilly city. I simply wasn't strong enough to ride up half the gradients I found in the city, whilst being a breeze on my MTBs.

In that moment my best alternative wast to change the freewheel. I'm struggling to remember, but I think the replacement was a 14-32, and that was a good enough for my case. With that change I was able to ride up most gradients. I sill had a hard time on the steepest hills but the whole investment was the equivalent to a couple US$ (Freewheel + chain).

The good thing is that since the smallest sprocket was the same as the original, I kept the original top gear ratio.
The rear derailleur worked just fine with the larger freewheel. The shifters where friction type.

I think the bike had enough space to fit a 7 speed F.W. (the gap between the frame and small sprocket was about two chain widths) but that would have cost too much at the time for I had no job and no income.

Answer (score 0):

> It current has a 170mm 52/42 custom (brand name) crankset

I recommend changing the crankset to 50/34 "compact" gearing (110mm BCD, probably not the same as your BCD in the 52/42 chainrings so a simple chainring swap is not enough), and possibly putting a new wider range rear cassette / freewheel if you can find a compatible one (the latter change might require finding a new rear derailleur so that's the lowest priority change of the two). This way, you won't need to change the front shifter at all, if indexed, and using the front shifter is easy, if friction shifting.

Triple with friction shifting requires careful adjustment in the middle chainring in order to not rub. So you don't want to use it. Triple with indexed shifting requires a shifter with three positions so a double index shifter is not compatible.

I don't see why anyone would like a road triple unless hauling very heavy loads. It may have been an okayish idea for narrow-range cassettes but usually today you can find a wide enough range cassette that a triple is completely pointless. With a 34-tooth chainring, if I'm using a bigger rear sprocket than 24-tooth, I'm almost invariably riding so slowly up a steep hill that staying balanced is a major chore and besides the speed is nearly as slow as walking speed so I can much rather push the bike up such steep hills.

Comment: "I recommend changing the crankset to 50/34 "compact" gearing"    I like this idea.

Comment: Triples are a solution for when the block has limited range, and OP has a 6 speed. That is likely to have some large jumps in tooth count, so a triple helps with gear range.

Comment: Would the downvoter like to comment ?

Comment: 2x6 road blocks tended to have a fairly small range on the stock block (and a jump or two) so a triple would help there as @Criggie suggests, without a new/rebuilt wheel to allow a major upgrade to the sprockets.

Comment: Not my DV but the last para seems excessive.  There's a huge  gap between the 34:24 in the answer and the 30:32 lowest gear on my tourer.  That's much better than pushing up hill, even without being laden. 34:24 at walking pace is only ~30rpm, compared to about 45rpm with 30:32.  Still pretty slow and grindy